# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs while booting

Tags: dual-boot

I have ubuntu 18.04 installed alongside windows 10, I've been having this issue lately. When I boot into Ubuntu after the splash screen many [ok] messages appear and it just hangs there, yet windows boot normally tho.
I tried reparing packages through recovery mode but didn't work, I also chose an older kernel but still face the same problem.

Kernel: 4.15.0-34- generic/4.15.0-33-generic

Pc: i5, 4 ram, intel hd graphics 4400

Comment: When you see the [OK] messages, are any of the lines, especially the last one, in RED? Do you see any error messages on this same screen? What does the very last line say? Have you run fsck on the Ubuntu partition? Have you installed a driver in W10 that allows you to read/write to the Ubuntu ext4 file system?

Answer (score 0):

must be a problem with your installation! try reinstalling by using the .iso file from the given link. torrent downloads are always best! https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads. Download the desktop file from the link. Hope it helps!

Comment: Will I lose all my data if I do so?

Comment: that's not sure, but there are chances, so backup all your data onto external hard disk or anything like that, I installed 16.04 over 10.04 but data was not lost, however i had all of my data backed up, so no worries, try this step only after BACKUP of all your DATA